# Angular 4 Как сделать больше одного http запроса в одном методе

Tags: httpclient, angular4

В сервисе я хочу создать метод, который будет отправлять одновременно два запроса на резные url (this.http.get(`${url}`). Первый запрос должен возвращать массив, а другой объект. И результаты помещаю в созданный объект под соответствующими названиями (obj.array, obj.object) который метод должен возвращать. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как правильно возвращать данные, ведь каждый из запросов возвращает Observable. Помогите пожалуйста, если можно с кодом, буду осень благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От опытного разработчика узнал о такой штуке, как `Observable.forkJoin()`.

Для использования нужно установить Rx.js в проект, а потом импортить туда где делается запрос
(`import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin'`)
Аргументами данного метода будут запросы, возвращает он массив типа `Observable`. Можно использовать в отдельном методе в сервисе, а потом в компоненте через метод Rx.js `.subscribe()` обрабатывать данные.

Пример:

**service.ts**

```
getJsonArray(){
    return Observable.forkJoin(
      this.http.get('website.com/cars.json'),
      this.http.get('website.com/boats.json')
    );
}
```

**component.ts**

```
myCars: any[];
myBoats: any[];

constructor(private service: YourServiceName){}

ngOnInit(){
    this.service.getJsonArray().subscribe(data => {
        this.myCars = data[0];
        this.myBoats = data[1];
    });
}
```